# How to reset browser's scroll state between page reloads?

Tags: browser, refresh, user-experience, page-refresh

The default behavior for browsers on page reload is to scroll back to the position where you last were on the page.

Let's say you scrolled to features section and then you hit F5. The browser will reload the page but it will remember the position you were at and scroll to features section.

Does anyone know how to reset this scroll state in browsers? In my application I need the browser to load page naturally and position the page on top on every page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

There is not something that you can "configure" to avoid that behavior because that's the browser behavior.

What you can do is to add a simple javascript when the page has been loaded to scroll to the top (if you already are on the top, this will do nothing):

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

To know when the page has been loaded, you can use jQuery document on load functionality if you are using jQuery, the equivalent on your javascript framework or the body onload property to place a function that execute the above code.